# centering the third div inside the container div

Tags: html, css

I am trying to figure out on centering this specific div block, the container has 3 div box which is the homeBox, awayBox, and newGame. the first two boxes are in the perfect position because I use the flexbox but the issue is the third div block is out of position, I try to write a `display flex` set it to `align-item: center` for the class of newGame but it doesn't work.

[image: The third div block is the button which is on the right side of the container]

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: "Karla", sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  background-color: hsl(204, 43%, 93%);
}

section {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 100px 30px;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  max-width: 650px;
  max-height: 385px;
  background: #1b244a;
  border-radius: 20px;
  position: relative;
}

.container>div {
  padding: 30px;
}

h3 {
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  font-size: 40px;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}

.scoreBox {
  background: black;
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 155px;
  min-height: 120px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.scoreBox h1 {
  color: red;
  font-size: 6.8em;
}

.scoreBtn {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.scoreBtn>* {
  padding: 10px 10px;
}

.scoreBtn button {
  background-color: transparent;
  width: 45px;
  height: 45px;
  border-color: #9aabd8;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Karla', sans-serif;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.scoreBtn button:hover {
  background-color: #408c99;
}

.newGame {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.newGame button {
  box-shadow: 0px 10px 14px -7px #276873;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #599bb3 5%, #408c99 100%);
  background-color: #599bb3;
  border-radius: 8px;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 13px 5px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px #3d768a;
  font-family: 'Karla', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.newGame button:hover {
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #408c99 5%, #599bb3 100%);
  background-color: #408c99;
}

.newGame button:active {
  position: relative;
  top: 1px;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="homeBox">
      <h3>HOME</h3>
      <div class="scoreBox">
        <h1 id="scoreHome">0</h1>
      </div>

      <div class="scoreBtn">
        <button>+1</button>
        <button>+2</button>
        <button>+3</button>
      </div>


    </div>
    <div class="awayBox">
      <div class="awayBox">
        <h3>AWAY</h3>
        <div class="scoreBox">
          <h1 id="scoreAway">0</h1>
        </div>

        <div class="scoreBtn">
          <button>+1</button>
          <button>+2</button>
          <button>+3</button>
        </div>


      </div>
      <div class="newGame">
        <button>New Game</button>
      </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: It's inside the awayBox, so makes sense that it's sticking to that box. Seems like you should move it outside that box. Please add the desired output.

Comment: You are missing to close ```<div>``` for ```awaybox```.

Comment: It seems i made a mistake from copying the homeBox content to awayBox, I close the div now the newGame is aligning from the right how can i move it below and center it?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

margin: auto;

to .newGame button

Answer (score 0):

Have in mind that .newgame is inside the .awayBox
So, to center .newgame button relative to that box, just remove

```
.newGame {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

from .newGame and change it with:

```
.newGame {
  text-align:center;
}
```

If you want to center it relative to the two upper divs, move the html out of awayBox

Answer (score 0):

you have a div not closing. awayBox is double used!

What about using a grid? Grid is really to build 2 dimensions structure.

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: "Karla", sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  background-color: hsl(204, 43%, 93%);
}

section {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 100px 30px;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  gap: 30px;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  max-width: 650px;
  max-height: 385px;
  background: #1b244a;
  border-radius: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
  position: relative;
}

.container>div {
  align-self: center;
  justify-self: center;
}

.homeBox {
  grid-area: 1 / 1 / 2 / 2;
}

.awayBox {
  grid-area: 1 / 2 / 2 / 3;
}

.newGame {
  grid-area: 2 / 1 / 3 / 3;
}

h3 {
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  font-size: 40px;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}

.scoreBox {
  background: black;
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 155px;
  min-height: 120px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.scoreBox h1 {
  color: red;
  font-size: 6.8em;
}

.scoreBtn {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.scoreBtn>* {
  padding: 10px 10px;
}

.scoreBtn button {
  background-color: transparent;
  width: 45px;
  height: 45px;
  border-color: #9aabd8;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Karla', sans-serif;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.scoreBtn button:hover {
  background-color: #408c99;
}

.newGame button {
  box-shadow: 0px 10px 14px -7px #276873;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #599bb3 5%, #408c99 100%);
  background-color: #599bb3;
  border-radius: 8px;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 13px 5px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px #3d768a;
  font-family: 'Karla', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.newGame button:hover {
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #408c99 5%, #599bb3 100%);
  background-color: #408c99;
}

.newGame button:active {
  position: relative;
  top: 1px;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="homeBox">
      <h3>HOME</h3>
      <div class="scoreBox">
        <h1 id="scoreHome">0</h1>
      </div>

      <div class="scoreBtn">
        <button>+1</button>
        <button>+2</button>
        <button>+3</button>
      </div>


    </div>
    <div class="awayBox">
      <h3>AWAY</h3>
      <div class="scoreBox">
        <h1 id="scoreAway">0</h1>
      </div>

      <div class="scoreBtn">
        <button>+1</button>
        <button>+2</button>
        <button>+3</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="newGame">
      <button>New Game</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd introduce `rows`, with the class `container-row`.

This way you can change the formatting of each row so the button is nicely centered in the middle below the other row

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: "Karla", sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  background-color: hsl(204, 43%, 93%);
}

section {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 100px 30px;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  max-width: 650px;
  max-height: 385px;
  background: #1b244a;
  border-radius: 20px;
  position: relative;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.container>div {
  padding: 30px;
}

.container-row {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.space-around {
  justify-content: space-around;
}

h3 {
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  font-size: 40px;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}

.scoreBox {
  background: black;
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 155px;
  min-height: 120px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.scoreBox h1 {
  color: red;
  font-size: 6.8em;
}

.scoreBtn {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.scoreBtn>* {
  padding: 10px 10px;
}

.scoreBtn button {
  background-color: transparent;
  width: 45px;
  height: 45px;
  border-color: #9aabd8;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Karla', sans-serif;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.scoreBtn button:hover {
  background-color: #408c99;
}

.newGame {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.newGame button {
  box-shadow: 0px 10px 14px -7px #276873;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #599bb3 5%, #408c99 100%);
  background-color: #599bb3;
  border-radius: 8px;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 13px 5px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px #3d768a;
  font-family: 'Karla', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.newGame button:hover {
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #408c99 5%, #599bb3 100%);
  background-color: #408c99;
}

.newGame button:active {
  position: relative;
  top: 1px;
}
```

```html
<section>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="container-row space-around">
            <div class="homeBox">
                <h3>HOME</h3>
                <div class="scoreBox">
                    <h1 id="scoreHome">0</h1>
                </div>
                <div class="scoreBtn">
                    <button>+1</button>
                    <button>+2</button>
                    <button>+3</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="awayBox">
                <div class="awayBox">
                    <h3>AWAY</h3>
                    <div class="scoreBox">
                        <h1 id="scoreAway">0</h1>
                    </div>
                    <div class="scoreBtn">
                        <button>+1</button>
                        <button>+2</button>
                        <button>+3</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container-row">
            <div class="newGame">
                <button>New Game</button>
            </div>
        </div>    
    </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

I fix the problem by using the grid and also I find some problems in your HTML Code so here are the codes.

HTML Code:

```
 <section>
        <div class="container">
          <div class="homeBox">
             <h3>HOME</h3>
             <div class="scoreBox">
                 <h1 id="scoreHome">0</h1>
             </div>
             <div class="scoreBtn">
                 <button>+1</button>
                 <button>+2</button>
                 <button>+3</button>
             </div>
          </div>
          <div class="newGame">
            <button>New Game</button>
          </div>
          <div class="awayBox">
            <div class="awayBox">
              <h3>AWAY</h3>
              <div class="scoreBox">
                <h1 id="scoreAway">0</h1>
              </div>
              <div class="scoreBtn">
                    <button>+1</button>
                    <button>+2</button>
                    <button>+3</button>
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

CSS Code:

```
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: "Karla", sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  background-color: hsl(204, 43%, 93%);
}

section {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 100px 30px;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(200px , 1fr));
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  max-width: 650px;
  max-height: 385px;
  background: #1b244a;
  border-radius: 20px;
  position: relative;
}

.container>div {
  padding: 30px;
}

h3 {
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  font-size: 40px;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}

.scoreBox {
  background: black;
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 155px;
  min-height: 120px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.scoreBox h1 {
  color: red;
  font-size: 6.8em;
}

.scoreBtn {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.scoreBtn>* {
  padding: 10px 10px;
}

.scoreBtn button {
  background-color: transparent;
  width: 45px;
  height: 45px;
  border-color: #9aabd8;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Karla', sans-serif;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.scoreBtn button:hover {
  background-color: #408c99;
}

.newGame {
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
}

.newGame button {
  box-shadow: 0px 10px 14px -7px #276873;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #599bb3 5%, #408c99 100%);
  background-color: #599bb3;
  border-radius: 8px;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 13px 5px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px #3d768a;
  font-family: 'Karla', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.newGame button:hover {
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #408c99 5%, #599bb3 100%);
  background-color: #408c99;
}

.newGame button:active {
  position: relative;
  top: 1px;
}
```